# Convert image of point data to a 2D boolean array

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I want to convert the following image to a 2D boolean array.

[image]

I have not had much experience with image-processing libraries before, but some shallow googling gives me libraries which do not seem to apply (such as converting an image to a desired format like jpeg, png, etc, OR, some common image editing tasks, like grayscale, resizing, etc, etc). I need some kind of object recognition library to compute the X and Y indices of each dot.

In addition to the coordinates of the squares, I want to be able to get the count of rows and columns.

Comment: How is your image represented? Is it a file? RGB values? Some encoded string? Does the separating line have a constant width (probably 1 px)? Are the black squares always rounded? With a constant radius? Do the blocks have constant width or height? Is there smoothing or can the edges be considered as pure black/white?

Comment: I'm really not sure what the problem is here. Any simple graphics library will allow you to load an image and inspect the value of each pixel ([LibGD](http://libgd.bitbucket.org/) would be my first choice). If the grid size is always 14 pixels, then just measure the width and height of the image (minus any white border), subtract 1 and divide by 14 to get the number of cells horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage did you use that library and conclude the grid size is 14px? Is there a python port of libgd?

Comment: @deostroll No, I opened the file in a graphics editor and counted them. Is there a python port of libgd? [Try asking Google.](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=libgd+python)

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to solve this problem is using [erosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29). You could use [openCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) library for this operation. Create a square kernel whose side is at least 14px and then erode the image. On erosion, you will have an image like this:[image: Eroded image].

You will have the pixel locations of all the centers of squares. However, it will also contain lines. These are present where two or more squares are located next to each other. You will have to eliminate them using an algorithm where no two pixels can reside in a circular radius of 14px.

Comment: How were you able to find the top left corner coordinate programmatically? Whats the logic behind it?

Comment: You don't have to. The top left corner coordinate is `(1,1)` when you load the image.

Comment: For erosion to work the top left of the grid, not the image file, should be the origin, right? Perhaps in my case that is incidentally at (1, 1)

Comment: Assume there was some space bw the grid top left corner and image top and left sides. How would you then determine the coordinate of the grid's top left corner?

Comment: So, when you load the image, the coordinates of first non-zero pixel from left and first non-zero pixel from top will provide the grid's top left corner.